Heatmap plot with weirdly shaped data
so I am trying to create a heatmap plot for x, y data that are shaped as following:
xs, ys, corrs = [], [], []
for x in np.linspace(0.1,5,25):
    xs.append(x)
    for y in np.linspace(0.01,x,25):
        ys.append(y)
        corr = function_to_calculte_corr()
        corrs.append(corr)

Now I would like to make a heatplot of corrs in the xs, ys plane. I have tried multiple times both with imshow and pcolormesh but do not seem to find the correct way. The problem is that the ys are differently spaced for each x value and they arrive until the corresponding x value, so I should be getting a plot where above the diagonal y=x should be blank.
Any help with it? Thanks in advance :)

You could try something like the following. However, you might have to scale the marker size to make it look nicer and you need to transform the results of function_to_calculate_corr() so that they are bounded between 0 and 1:
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

def function_to_calculate_corr():
    return np.random.random_integers(0,1000,1)/1000

def marker_sizing_function(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    #Scale the marker size according to the x value
    return 2

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
color_map = cm.get_cmap('viridis', 12)
for x in np.linspace(0.1,5,25):
    for y in np.linspace(0.01,x,25):
        corr = function_to_calculate_corr()
        axes.scatter(x,y,marker = "s", color = color_map(corr), s = 
        marker_sizing_function(x, y))
plt.show()
plt.close()


Thanks a lot! It's not exactly what I wanted, because I was looking for a heatmap but it serves me to visualize the data at least so thanks!!
